# How to use a single function to merge different lists using a parent/child structure?

Tags: r, list, lapply

The example code presented at the bottom creates a function `createBucket()` which does a fine job of reading through the elements in the `dfVector` vector and `dfList` list and creating an expanded parent/child list of list/sublists, as shown in the left half of the image below.

Next, I would like to merge a list comprised of the `baVector` and `inVector` vectors, such list named "total", into the results of running function `createBucket()` as illustrated the right half of the image below. This merged list would be at the same level as $DF_One and $DF_Two, with parent name $Total and child sublist names $baVector and $inVector, as illustrated in the right half of the image below. Any suggestions for how to modify `createBucket()` so that it merges the "Total" list with the rest of the list?

I'd like to keep the list merger code in the same `createBucket()` function instead of creating another function that draws on the `createBucket()` function and merges the lists that way. I already tried replacing the `series` at the of the `createBucket()` function with `c(total, series)`, but that gives error "*Error in names(object) <- nm : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [2]*"

[image]

Code:

```
dfVector <- function() {c("DF_One", "DF_Two")}
dfList <- list(DF_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), DF_Two = c("Rat", "Bat"))
baVector <- c(1000,1000,1000)
inVector <- c(6,5,4)

createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  
  total <- list(
    baVector = baVector,
    inVector = inVector
  )
  
  series <- dfVector()
  setNames(
    lapply(series, \(series_name) {
      setNames(
        lapply(dfList[[series_name]], \(element) {
          df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nbr_rows, 2))
          colnames(df) <- c('A', 'B')
          df
        }),
        dfList[[series_name]]
      )
    }),
    series
  )
}

tmp <- createBucket(2)
tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  
  total <- list(
    Total = list(
      baVector = baVector,
      inVector = inVector
    )
  )
  
  series <- dfVector()
  merged_list <- c(total, lapply(series, function(series_name) {
    setNames(
      lapply(dfList[[series_name]], function(element) {
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nbr_rows, 2))
        colnames(df) <- c('A', 'B')
        df
      }),
      dfList[[series_name]]
    )
  }))
  
  names(merged_list) <- c(names(total), series)
  
  return(merged_list)
}
```